# Javascript select the string if it matches multiple words in array

Tags: javascript

I have a string "There are multiple words in this string" and I have an array with multiple words ["There", "string", "multiple"]. I want to match my string with this array and it should return true if all the words in the array are present in the string. If any one of the word in the array is not present in the string, it should return false.

```
 var str = "There are multiple words in this string";
 var arr = ["There", "string", "multiple"]
```

This should return true.

```
 var str = "There are multiple words in this string";
 var arr = ["There", "hello", "multiple"]
```

This should return false since "hello" is not present in the string.

How can this be done efficiently in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Impress your teacher: `arr.every(Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(str.split(' '))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Array.prototype.every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), that returns true if all elements pass the condition :

```
var str = "There are multiple words in this string";
var arr = ["There", "string", "multiple"]
var arr2 = ["There", "hello", "multiple"]

var result = arr.every(function(word) {
    // indexOf(word) returns -1 if word is not found in string
    // or the value of the index where the word appears in string
    return  str.indexOf(word) > -1
})
console.log(result) // true

result = arr2.every(function(word) {
    return  str.indexOf(word) > -1
})
console.log(result) // false
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cl3MM/wkqfdtvc/)

Comment: nice one. Although in the example code, `arr2` is probably wrong. JSFiddle is good.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every),

```
var str = "There are multiple words in this string";
var arr = ["There", "string", "multiple"]
var res = arr.every(function(itm){
 return str.indexOf(itm) > -1;
});

console.log(res); //true
```

But note that `indexOf()` will do a wildcard search, that means

```
"Therearemultiplewordsinthisstring".indexOf("There")
```

will also return an index other than `-1`. And it is case sensitive.